# Automating Xcode with Applescript

Tags: xcode, applescript

I was googling around, but couldn't find docs for functionality exposed by Xcode through AppleScript (if any?)
Basically, I'm trying to automate certain things that are not doable through xcodebuild.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish though controlling xcode to do stuff because most of the stuff xcode can build (besides interface builders) can be done via the command line eg. Xcode compiles executables with the "clang" command

Comment: I'm automating a build process and adding some capabilities. xcodebuild has no options for that

Comment: can you please give an example of what your doing building with capabilities, that might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionalities exposed by Xcode through AppleScript can be seen in the dictionary of Script Editor.

Open Script Editor and access dictionary by going to File > Open Dictionary.

[Pictorial reference to open dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8ftH.png)

A new window will open, scroll down to Xcode and click choose.

[Pictorial reference to choose Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z96e5.png)

The next window will show all the keywords and functionalities exposed by Xcode through AppleScript that you can use to automate things.

[Preview of Xcode Dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDY4Y.png)